# Java Compilation Rule

Tags: java, compilation

In the main-method class of my program, I created objects of other classes. Do I need to compile not only the main-method class, but also the other classes?

My code looks something like this:

```
public class GameLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GuessGame newGame = new GuessGame();
        newGame.startGame();
    }
}
```

```
public class GuessGame {
    Player p1;
    Player p2;
    Player p3;
    int targetNumber;

    public void startGame() {
    }
}
```

```
public class Player {
    private int number;

    public int guess() {
    }
}
```

When I only compiled the main-method class, the Player objects only returned 0 as their guesses (the actual guess function had code in it). After I compiled all three classes, the program run as expected.

I am just wondering what the logic behind this rule is. I originally thought that when an unknown, new class is encountered during compilation, the javac program knows that it will need to compile the encountered source file itself.

Comment: Please show a [mcve], including but not limited to the commands you used to compile the code.

Comment: If a relevant source file wasn't compiled, the code would crash with a `NoSuchClassError` on run. The fact that it _did_ run means your code ran fine and simply returned 0 (i.e. had a bug in it). Of course, if you had compiled `Player.java` before that probably means the old version remained and caused the unexpected output. Nobody* uses `javac` directly, everybody uses a build system such as maven or gradle. (*: Rounded down).

Answer (score 0):

For compiling `GameLauncher.java` the java compiler needs the class file of the `GuessGame` class. If that class file doesn't exist but the java compiler finds the `GuessGame.java` file it compiles it automatically. Similarly for the `Player` class file and the `Player.java` file.

**But** the java compiler does not check whether `GuessGame.java` was changed after the `GuessGame` class file has been created. If you change the `GuessGame.java` file after the `GuessGame` class file has been created it is your responsability to either delete the `GuessGame` class file or manually compile `GuessGame.java`.

In your simple example it is easy to just always delete all class files before compiling `GameLauncher.java`, but in a more complex project you don't want to delete all class files and compile all source files again - you want to compile only the source files that have changed and the source files that depend on the changed source files.

That is why everyone uses a build system - build systems do those checks for you.